# Получить маршрут по прошедшей дате

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я пытаюсь использовать апи получения маршрута по заданным координатам, но в качестве даты используется дата из прошлого.
Мне выдается следующая ошибка:

```
{"errors":["parameter \u0027departure_time\u0027 is in the past: 1542621729"]}
```

У меня возникло два вопроса:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что апи не поддерживает поиск по
   прошедшим периодам?
2. Как долго кешируются данные для расчета
   маршрута.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

API строит прогноз пробок на время в будущем (с учётом исторических пробок), но не возвращает точное время маршрута в прошлом. То есть не хранит снепшоты пробок в прошлом.